# Rsync-based Backup solution for Kubuntu

Tags: backup, rsync, home-server, kubuntu, incremental-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic backup solution for Linux (maybe a GUI for rsync)?](https://superuser.com/questions/72902/automatic-backup-solution-for-linux-maybe-a-gui-for-rsync)

hey there

I am kinda a bit lost in the multiple options so any recommendations will be more then welcomed. I am looking for a simple backup solution (just installed the latest Kubuntu (11)). Here is a not-so-long wishlist:

1. `rsync`-based
2. incremental backup
3. provides kinda usable GUI frontend (KDE-based is a strong plus)
4. *update:* downloadable/installable via the standard package manager (apt) to be able to get all the updates in a well-formed/standardized way

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've read it before posting. First, it's 2 years old. Second, IF I've got it right, it's more on Gtk-side, rather then KDE-side. Third, the SBackup is not rsync-based, hence, not sure that incremental backup is supported. I apologize in prior if I haven't got the things right from that post - if so - please correct me and I'll delete this question or will do whatever appropriate. Thanks

Comment: @BreakPhreak If you check the bottom line of the only answer, you'll find an rsync GUI for Kommander (=KDE) as well. The project is still available today! (:

Comment: I've seen that, tried to find kommander, installed it, tried to find the krsync, could't see it in the packages' list, gave up a bit. So strange that there is no next-next-next simple integrated solution. Don't get me wrong, I've worked as a *nix developer for years, but as the time goes by, when it's not about my job - looking for the things that work out-of-the box. Perhaps, it's still not the time, perhaps I want too much. Anyways, if there will be no answer in days - it means that the answer in the link, listed by you is still the most recent/actual.

Comment: @BreakPhreak http://kde-apps.org/content/download.php?content=68586&id=1&tan=44975112 ?

Comment: sure, but why not via the package manager to get all the updates automatically and on time?

Comment: PS: just updated the question. But I guess that the answer will be "there is no such a solution". I do keep an rsync time-machine-like script in my sleeve, but still keep some hope for a ready-made out-of-the-box well-integrated solution for dummies (I am such a lazy nerd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/info.html) has a nice Web-based front end and extremely good full/incremental backup management:

*BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade system for backing up Linux and WinXX PCs and laptops to a server's disk. BackupPC is highly configurable and easy to install and maintain.
BackupPC is written in Perl and extracts backup data via SMB using Samba, tar over ssh/rsh/nfs, or rsync. It is robust, reliable, well documented and freely available as Open Source on SourceForge.*

Comment: Thanks, marking your as an answer, listing the alternative option I am evaluating first. Assume that both options fit the criteria, enlisted above, hence both are the correct answers. If your experience proves otherwise - please share. Thanks again.

Comment: PS: The interface of BackupPC looked less intuitive to me as I don't want to mess with rsync RTFM-ing). Still, trying to get on track with BackInTime.

Answer (score 0):

`BackupPC` is a cool software to try, but I've got my fingers on `BackInTime` utility (http://backintime.le-web.org/) that does everything I need (and listed). One day I might compare those two, but for now the question is closed for me. Still, @Linker3000, thanks for answering - seems to be equally valid option.